# how to get the number of rows of an excel file in java using POI - getPhysicalNumberOfRows() does not work

Tags: java, apache-poi

I wanted to get the number of rows of an excel sheet. I used getPhysicalNumberOfRows() function from POI library, my excel table original had 5 rows including the header row. Then I deleted 2 rows of records from the file and saved, but during the debug process I sill get 5 rows when I make a call to getPhysicalNumberOfRows().
Any one knows what can cause this wired problem?

Comment: If it is as you describes, then you are not deleting the rows, at least not physically. Maybe you are deleting the content of the rows but not the rows itself. But without knowing the code you are using, this is not to answer. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows the problem.

Comment: @user1836957 Rather than just checking the total number of rows, check the content of rows also to verify Axels'  thought.

Comment: We use Excel sheets that see a lot of copy, cutting and pasting as input and read them with the POI library. Depending on the user actions in Excel rows might appear empty but are still present. So I strongly recommend checking for the content of rows/cells to tell whether a row is empty or not!